# How do i push my microservice folders to Github as one repository

Tags: laravel, git, git-commit, laravel-9, git-gui

I have a micro-service app built in Laravel 9. It is built as two micro-services: frontend and backend.

Each micro-service has sub-folders and file because each is a Laravel installation.
[image: My repository structure]

I want to commit the whole as one repository to GitHub using my Git GUI but my windows shows no files and i keep getting :

> No changes to commit
> You must stage at least 1 file before you can commit.

[image: My Git GUI]

Answer (score 0):

Prior to committing, you must add files.

Some commands for git flow:

`git init` creates new repository

`git add <filename>` stages a file

`git add *` or `git add --all` stages all files on the repository

`git commit -m "message"` commits staged files

`git push <remote> <branch>` Pushes branch to a remote repository e.g. on github

Some basic documentation:
https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll look up that Git guide.